# Linq to EF .Clear() does not clear

Tags: c#, linq, collections, entity-framework-4, entitycollection

```
EntityCollection.ToList().Clear()
```

Does not clear the entity collection. Any idea why?

Any solution?

How should i clear the `EntityCollection`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `ToList()` creates a copy of the EntityCollection as a `List<T>` and then you just clear that list and not the `EntityCollection` itself.

Edit 1:
Use the `Clear()` method from EntityCollection:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb302707.aspx

Edit 2:
Oh I see. So it's this class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff422654(v=vs.91).aspx ?
Seems you have to enumerate all items and delete them one by one.

```
foreach( var item in EntityCollection.ToList() )
    EntityCollection.Remove(item);
```

Here you need `ToList()` to create a copy because most of the collection classes don't like it when you delete items from them during enumeration.

Comment: EntityCollection does not have Clear()

Comment: As I said with the Clear() method from EntityCollection. Just postet the msdn link.

Comment: The EntityCollection is part of this namespace: 
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Entity .. DO not have Clear()

Comment: Then it's not the ADO.NET EF although the classes have the same name and simelar members. Think about retagging your question with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcf-ria-services

Answer (score 0):

`ToList()` generates a new list (you are clearing that).