# Entity Framework: Why can I not empty a collection in this Many-to-Many relations?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the `Course` entity that holds a collection of `Students`, and they are in a Many-to-Many relationship, as per tutorial [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

I can add a Student object with `course.Students.Add(student);`, but I cannot remove it with none of the following:

```
// Using Clear()
course.Students.Clear();


// Manually removing
foreach (var item in course.Students)
{
    course.Students.Remove(item);
}

//Forcefully reassign
course.Students = new List<Student>();
```

Can someone tell me why that is? I tried follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408305/linq-to-ef-clear-does-not-clear), but no avail. I think I may have to manually remove it from the join table below, but mine is automatically created so I can't access it.

Joint table `CourseStudent`
[image]

Course class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Library
{
    public class Course
    {
        public Course()
        {
            this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        }

        public string CourseId { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }

        public string Department {get; set;}

        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Student class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Library
{
    public class Student
    {
        public Student() 
        {
            this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
        }

        public string StudentId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My method (azure function)

```
[FunctionName("UpdateCourse")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCourse(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "put", Route = "courses/{CourseId}")]
HttpRequest req,
ILogger log, string CourseId) {

    var course = await _context.Courses.FindAsync(CourseId);

// course.Students.Clear();

    foreach (var item in course.Students)
    {
        course.Students.Remove(item);
    }


    _context.Update(course);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return new OkObjectResult(removeSelfReference(course));
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Here are parts of my code-first migration files for the join table `CourseStudent`

20220415034607_M1.cs:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "CourseStudent",
    columns: table => new
    {
        CoursesCourseId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
        StudentsStudentId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_CourseStudent", x => new { x.CoursesCourseId, x.StudentsStudentId });
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_CourseStudent_Courses_CoursesCourseId",
            column: x => x.CoursesCourseId,
            principalTable: "Courses",
            principalColumn: "CourseId",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_CourseStudent_Students_StudentsStudentId",
            column: x => x.StudentsStudentId,
            principalTable: "Students",
            principalColumn: "StudentId",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

20220415034607_M1.Designer.cs:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("CourseStudent", b =>
    {
        b.HasOne("Library.Course", null)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("CoursesCourseId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .IsRequired();

        b.HasOne("Library.Student", null)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("StudentsStudentId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .IsRequired();
    });
```

Comment: *I cannot remove it* - You mean "why can I not delete it from the database?"

Comment: *`foreach (var item in course.Students) course.Students.Remove(item);`* - modifying a collection while enumerating is prohibited in c# generally

Comment: @CaiusJard that's correct, I cannot remove it from the database, but more specifically there is a automatically created join table that only exist in the db with the relations that are not removed. My bad for omitting this, post has just been updated.

Comment: What is your delete cascade  setting set to?

Comment: @CaiusJard, just added Edit 1 to include it. It was set to Cascade.

Comment: Is this ef6 or ef core?

Comment: @Lee It is EntityFrameworkCore, version 6.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you verify that your course is lazy loading students? If lazy loading is disabled then course.Students will be empty. When modifying the collection of students you should be eager-loading it regardless:

```
var course = context.Courses
    .Include(x => x.Students)
    .Single(x => x.CourseId == courseId);
```

From there you should be able to use:

```
course.Students.Clear();
```

since Course.Students will be a proxy that EF recognizes and the Clear method will mark all entries for removal. With many-to-many relationships you may need to dis-associate the course from each of the students:

```
var course = context.Courses
    .Include(x => x.Students)
    .Single(x => x.CourseId == courseId);

foreach(var student in course.Students)
    student.Courses.Remove(course);

course.Students.Clear();
context.SaveChanges();
```

to be sure that the references are removed in the event that any of the students might be marked as modified.

Lastly, with tracked entities, just call `SaveChanges()`rather than calling `Update`. `Update` is for untracked/detached entities.